# how to retrieve all authors for each Scopus record in a query

Tags: scopus

I have retrieved some records from Scopus using `elsapy`, using this search query:

```
search_query = 'TITLE-ABS-KEY(teleworking) AND SUBJAREA(SOCI)'
search_results = ElsSearch(search_query, 'scopus')
```

All is good except that the retrieved records only contain the first author for each paper.
Take for instance this record, with Scopus ID: 1542427662. If you have an API key, you can try:

```
https://api.elsevier.com/content/abstract/scopus_id/1542427662?apikey=your-api-key
```

All you got is the first author, but this paper actually has 6 authors. What is the proper way to retrieve all the authors connected to the paper?

Answer (score 1):

In that record, you can see the DOI:

```
<prism:doi>10.1146/annurev.soc.22.1.213</prism:doi>
```

Extract this DOI and use [*CrossRef*'s API](https://github.com/CrossRef/rest-api-doc) to fetch author data at `https://api.crossref.org/works/{DOI}`.

In our case, https://api.crossref.org/works/10.1146/annurev.soc.22.1.213 shows six authors in the `author` field.